# JasperReports: counting pages depending on group

Tags: java, jasper-reports

The problem is like this.

The report page numbers that are displayed on the page should not be dependent on the current but on the group page.

Let me explain:

I have a report with 2 groups that has 4 pages, each group on two pages, and what I need to do is the following:

```
group 1 page 1: should be: 1/2 -> current: 1/4
group 1 page 2: should be: 2/2 -> current: 2/4
group 1 page 1: should be: 1/2 -> current: 3/4
group 1 page 2: should be: 2/2 -> current: 4/4
```

Is there any way this can be done ...

PS. No black magic allowed, I had a look at the variables that are defined in *JasperReports* but none of them fit the profile :)

Comment: Weird, V$PAGE_COUNT for me seemed to show the group number, so if I had 14 groups on a one page report that page would say 1 of 14.  You seem to be getting the opposite but want what I got?

Answer (score 1):

You could try setting setting the isResetPageNumber attribute of the group to true.

e.g. `<group  name="someGroupName" isResetPageNumber="true" >`

Answer (score 1):

user51931 answer is correct ! It also helpful to me.

You can also set this group property from design view.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Found this answer, and I was able to achieve that:

> I was able to resolve this issue by setting the 'evaluation time'
>   property to 'group' on the text field that contained my
>   $V{PAGE_NUMBER} variable.

Comment: Use both « isResetPageNumber="true" » for the group, and evaluationTime="Group" and evaluationGroup="<your group>" for the field which contains the total number of pages of the group (with expression text= $V{PAGE_NUMBER}).The current page number is just $V{PAGE_NUMBER}, with evaluationTime=now.