# Resetting page number based on grouping

Tags: jasper-reports

I wonder if it is possible to reset page number based on grouping?

My idea is like group 1 having 3 pages which will show Page 1 of 3, page 2 of 3 and page 3 of 3. And group 2 having 1 page which will show Page 1 of 1.

So the display will be:

```
Page 1 of 3
Page 2 of 3
Page 3 of 3
page 1 of 1
```

Is it possible to do that? I have searched all the web seems like can't find any clue and steps to do.

Source

```
<queryString language="SQL">
    <![CDATA[Select * from Persons where ID = $P{ID}]]>
</queryString>
<field name="ID" class="java.lang.Object"/>
<group name="myGroup" isStartNewPage="true" isResetPageNumber="true">
    <groupHeader>
        <band height="224">
            <subreport>
                <reportElement x="300" y="135" width="270" height="60" uuid="1f20858d-c055-41e2-9a60-bbc040ae6485"/>
                <subreportParameter name="ID_PERSON">
                    <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$F{ID}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                </subreportParameter>
                <connectionExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_CONNECTION}]]></connectionExpression>
                <subreportExpression><![CDATA["subreport_1.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
            </subreport>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="280" y="10" width="100" height="30" uuid="dacdfcd9-150b-419d-ba3b-b56949cd518d"/>
                <text><![CDATA[Group 1]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <break>
                <reportElement x="0" y="210" width="99" height="1" uuid="a77bf8e0-98ea-4167-b852-f2cb5f6e1cf6"/>
            </break>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="280" y="58" width="300" height="30" uuid="df9536c9-6584-43b3-b8b9-45fd0c0b95a6"/>
                <text><![CDATA[This report is to testing the grouping.]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <break>
                <reportElement x="0" y="111" width="100" height="1" uuid="6cda26ee-6e49-4e94-8d58-5d5dd42745e6"/>
            </break>
        </band>
    </groupHeader>
    <groupFooter>
        <band height="50"/>
    </groupFooter>
</group>
<group name="myGroup2" isStartNewPage="true" isResetPageNumber="true">
    <groupHeader>
        <band height="130">
            <subreport>
                <reportElement x="270" y="60" width="300" height="60" uuid="5663a0dc-9b14-485b-84a9-21b5e0c3b98d"/>
                <subreportParameter name="ID_PERSON">
                    <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$F{ID}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                </subreportParameter>
                <connectionExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_CONNECTION}]]></connectionExpression>
                <subreportExpression><![CDATA["subreport_2.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
            </subreport>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="280" y="20" width="100" height="30" uuid="eaa5ee0f-c0e5-4555-b321-a4db52b4efde"/>
                <text><![CDATA[Group 2]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </groupHeader>
    <groupFooter>
        <band height="58"/>
    </groupFooter>
</group>
<pageFooter>
    <band height="57" splitType="Stretch">
        <textField evaluationTime="Group" evaluationGroup="myGroup">
            <reportElement x="400" y="10" width="100" height="30" uuid="215676d9-e972-45bd-adad-b79c1fa27112"/>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{PAGE_NUMBER}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField>
            <reportElement x="310" y="10" width="110" height="30" uuid="75a82ec2-a8ed-46dd-b5a1-147c450e32f8"/>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{PAGE_NUMBER}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
    </band>
</pageFooter>
```

Comment: Did you try to use `isResetPageNumber` for group?

Comment: yes, I checked the function already, nothing happen. Seems like the expression for group i need to set variable for it so they can differentiate the group ?

Comment: Duplicates: [Jasper Reports: page x of y within one record](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11113824/876298) & [JasperReports: counting pages depending on group](https://stackoverflow.com/q/435385/876298) & [Reset Page Number in Ireport](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43806666/876298)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jasper Reports: page x of y within one record](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11113824/jasper-reports-page-x-of-y-within-one-record)

Comment: Already read thru those post,  seems like still not able to solve it